# neo4j cypher How to find existence count of a specific node in relations?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, match, shortest-path

In my application, i will try to calculate betweenness centrality of nodes. Here is the
[Betweenness Centrality Calculation Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaF8h.jpg). Deminator is just count of relationship between two nodes. But numerator is the existence count of a specific node between this relation. So how can i find the existence count of a node in the relation?

For example as a result of this cypher:`MATCH p=allShortestPaths( (u1{name:1174}) - [*..20] - (u2{name:1179}) ) return  p`

[A graph between 2 specific nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTnAw.png). how can i find the transition count of node:1204 on the relationships between nodes:1174-1179

Shortly, there are shortest paths between `node A` to `node B`. How many of them includes node `node C` ?

Comment: Please insert the images into your query. Also, please clarify the definition of “transition”.

Comment: hello @GaborSzarnyas,

now you can see the images by using links. Transition means; for example: in the shortests pathes from node "a" to node "c" how many of them includes the node "b" ?

Comment: Please insert them as images and not as links. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `nodes()` function on the path variable to get a collection of nodes for the given path. From there you can check if a specific previously matched node is present. Here's one way to do it:

```
MATCH (n{name:1204}) 
MATCH p=allShortestPaths( (u1{name:1174}) - [*..20] - (u2{name:1179}) ) 
WITH p, case when n in nodes(p) then 1 else 0 end as occurrences
RETURN count(p) as shortestPathCount, sum(occurrences) as occurrencesCount
```

Also, it's recommended you use labels in your graph and in your queries. Currently this is performing an all nodes scan to find any node with the given name, and that gets less and less efficient as the number of nodes grows. If you add a label on your nodes and use them in your match, then you'll at least be performing a label scan instead. If you create an index on the label/property then you'll be doing index lookups for starting nodes in your query.